# JAWS read select box without repeat before sentence

Tags: html, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I have a sentence like [image]. JAWS will read it as `hello hello combobox choose dot dot dot test question`. How can I guide JAWS to read without repeat `hello`? Expectation result is `hello combobox choose dot dot dot test question`.
The code of it as bellow:

```
<div class="text">
    <p>
        hello <span class="control group1">
            <select class="select custom-select" name="s">
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option value="1">first</option>
                <option value="2">second</option>
                <option value="3">third</option>
            </select> 
        </span> test question.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, what's on the image? I would love to answer your question, but as a JAWS user I'm totally blind, so I can't see your image. Second, when does JAWS repeat "hello hello"? How do you navigate: with Tab, arrows, `c` quick nav key for comboboxes? Thanks.

Comment: @AndrePolykanine thanks for your comment. The image is what the code at the end of my question will be rendered. When I focus to somewhere before `hello` then press `Insert + ↓`, JAWS will read from this position to the end of page. when it read the content of image, it will read `hello hello combobox choose dot dot dot test question`.

Answer (score 2):

Screenreaders will generally 'read' what's on the screen. You can get them to behave differently by using semantic html, or aria roles, which will make the screenreader treat the content as 'interactive'. In your case, you have a popup inside a paragraph. I think it's reading the paragraph twice, once as content, and then again as a kind of 'label' for the popup. It's improvising a label because the popup has no formal label.

Paragraphs are (generally) for reading/browsing, rather than interaction, so you should reconsider that choice. I can't give better advice, because I don't know what "hello" represents (other than a placeholder).

If you give the popup a formal label (either with a `<label>` element or an `aria-label` attribute JAWS wont need to guess the label (and guess wrong).

Comment: Thank you for your helpful advice. In my question, if [1] I focus to somewhere before `hello` then press `Insert + ↓`, JAWS will read `hello hello combobox ...`. If [2] I navigate to combo box by `tab`, JAWS will read `hello combobo ...`. It means, JAWS will always read the sentence before the combo box (context of combo box) then read the combo box. What I expect is avoid repeating the context in case [1] but keep it in case [2]. Is it possible?

Comment: Is "hello" supposed to be browseable text, or a label for the combobox? At the moment it's doing both jobs, so it will be read out twice, once in browse mode (not context, just a paragraph), then again as the screen reader enters interaction/forms mode, it announces the text node next to the interactive control (the 'context'). If you tab to it, you will only get the context. If you just want the label announced, but not the browseable text, make the label a proper `<label>` element, with a `for` attribute pointing at the id of the combobox (currently missing).

Comment: thank you @brennanyoung, based on your comment, I add a `aria-label` to select box and it resolved my issue.

Comment: This doesn't make it clear why this is happening. It's because there is no label. JAWS has clever algorithms to add a label if there is none. It often just uses the text before the label as it is quite likely to be text that describes the form element. So, the first "hello" is the text, the second "hello" is JAWS sort of adding its own label. And labels are always read out when focusing on form element. This is expected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @selfthinker I've now added those important details to the answer.